# Filtrar lista, Curso de Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

- Crea una función que se llame **filtrar** que reciba una lista de objetos cualquiera y el nombre de una clase, extrayendo los objetos de esa clase y meterlo en una lista nueva

```py
class Vehiculo:
    
    def __init__(self,color=None,ruedas=None):
        self.color=color
        self.ruedas=ruedas
        print("Constructor de la clase vehiculo creado")
        
    def __str__(self):
        return "--Su color es: {}\n --con ruedas: {}\n".format(self.color,self.ruedas)
    
def datos():

    a= input("Introduzca el color del vehiculo: ")
    b= input("Introduzca las ruedas del vehiculo: ")
    return a, b          

def filtrar(listado=[],tipo=Coche):

    listaCoches=[]
    coincidencias=filter(lambda Coche:Coche.color=="rojo",listado)
    for i in coincidencias:
        listaCoches.append(listado)
        print(i)
        
        #Aqui estoy intentando el metodo filtrar amigos pero no se como hacerlo me quedo estancado
        #Necesito filtrar la lista y las coincidencias en una lista nueva : / ayuda y muchas gracias
        #Lo he tratadod de hacer con la funcion lambda y sin ella, pero me quedo igual estancado
    
                          
class Coche(Vehiculo):
          
    def __init__(self,color=None,ruedas=None,velocidad=None,cilindrada=None):
        super().__init__(color,ruedas)
        self.velocidad= velocidad
        self.cilindrada=cilindrada
        print("Constructor de la clase coche creado")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()+"--Su velocidad es: {} km/h \n -- con una cilindrada de: {}cc \n".format(self.velocidad,
                                                                                                         self.cilindrada)

class Bicicleta(Vehiculo):

    def __init__(self,color=None,ruedas=None,tipo=None):
        super().__init__(color,ruedas)
        self.tipo=tipo
        print("Constructor de la clase Bicicleta creado")
        
    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()+"--su tipo es: {}\n".format(self.tipo)
    
class Camioneta(Vehiculo):

    def __init__(self,color=None,cargada=None):
        super().__init__(color,ruedas)
        self.cargada=cargada
        print("Constructor de la clase Camioneta creado")
        
    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()+"--la camioneta esta: {}\n".format(self.cargada)
    
class Motocicleta(Coche):

    `def __init__(self,color=None,ruedas=None,
                velocidad=None,cilindrada=None):
        super().__init__(color,ruedas,velocidad,cilindrada)
        print("Constructor de la clase Motocicleta creado")
        
 `def __str__(self):`   
        `return super().__str__()+"--Es de color: {}\n y tiene ruedas de: {}\n".format(self.color,self.ruedas)
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    
    listado=[]
    numlista=int(input("Cuantas vehiculos quiere añadir: "))
    for i in range(numlista):
        a,b = datos()
        listado.append((a,b))
        
    print("--"*60 )
    
    for lis in listado:
            print(lis)
            
    listaCoches = filtrar(listado, "Coche")
```

Comment: Y tu problema esta en?

Comment: Podrias poner un titulo que resuma el cuerpo de la pregunta por favor? El titulo actual es ruido casi en su totalidad.

Comment: `def filtrar (listado=[],listado2=[]):` Ahí tienes un problema.

Comment: Tu problema se reduce a esto: crear una función que reciba una lista de objetos cualquiera y el nombre de una clase, extrayendo los objetos de esa clase. No es necesario que pongas **todo** el código; sólo necesitas mostrar la función `filtrar`. Si editas tu pregunta y la simplificas, alguien la respondera.

Comment: @RuthIsRoot@Dante S@Candid Moe, Lo siento chicos es mi primera vez aqui registrado el profesor me la ha recomendado y aun no se utilizarla muy bien, seguramente he hecho un texto horrible : / sorry

Comment: @Kinderblack Tampoco se trata de que elimines tu código y dejes solo la pregunta, pues en ese caso simplemente parece que estás pidiendo que te resolvamos nosotros el problema y así poco vas a aprender. Lo que tienes que hacer es intentar implementar una solución, y si no lo consigues por una causa concreta preguntar acerca de esa causa, mostrando el mínimo código necesario para que podamos entender tu duda.

Comment: Estás destruyendo tu pregunta. Describe brevemente cuál es el problema y dale formato al código agregando triples acentos graves (```) antes de la primera y luego de la última línea del código. Así como está redactada tu pregunta, no se entiende qué se está preguntando. Por otra parte, redáctala de tal manera de que sea útil no solo para ti, sino también para los demás miembros de la comunidad, ya que este sitio _no es un foro_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función `filtrar` es lo importante, lo demás lo utilicé para verificar que funcionase.

```
class Persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.edad = edad

class Empleado(Persona):
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad, sueldo):
        super().__init__(nombre, edad)
        self.sueldo = sueldo

class Alumno(Persona):
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad, curso):
        super().__init__(nombre, edad)
        self.curso = curso

def filtrar(lista, clase):
    resultado = []
    for elemento in lista:
        if isinstance(elemento, clase):
            resultado.append(elemento)
            print(elemento.nombre, elemento.edad, clase)    # Solo para revisar que elementos se guardaron en resultado
    return resultado


lista = [
    Empleado("Juan", 23, 1000),
    Empleado("Pedro", 25, 2000),
    Alumno("Luis", 23, "Python"),
    Alumno("Marcos", 25, "Python"),
]


def filtrado(i):
    if i == 0:
        filtrar(lista, Empleado)
    elif i == 1:
        filtrar(lista, Alumno)
    elif i < 0:
        return
    else:
        print('El valor indicado es invalido')

estado = 0

while (estado >= 0):
    estado = int(input("¿Qué tipo de filtrado desea? (0: Empleado/1: Alumno): "))
    filtrado(estado)
```

Comment: La pregunta requiere el nombre de la clase como string ("Empleado"), no la clase (Empleado).

Comment: Puedes optar por usar un listado en donde recibe un numero, ya modifiqué el código de la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias chicos son unos crack

Answer (score 2):

Una solución simple:

```
def filtrar(lista, nombre_clase):
    return [elemento for elemento in lista if type(elemento).__name__ == nombre_clase]
```

Usamos una comprensión de lista con condición. Para verificar la condición necesitamos el **nombre** de clase del objeto, que obtenemos con la función `type(elemento).__name__`.

#### Demo

```
class Envase:
    def __init__(self, nombre, volumen):
       self.nombre = nombre
       self.volumen = volumen
       self.retornable = False

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Envase no retornable {self.nombre}, {self.volumen} cc"

class Retornable(Envase):
    def __init__(self, nombre, volumen):
        super().__init__(nombre, volumen)
        self.retornable = True

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Envase retornable {self.nombre}, {self.volumen} cc"

def filtrar(lista, nombre_clase):
    return [elemento for elemento in lista if type(elemento).__name__ == nombre_clase]

lista = [Envase("coca", 350), Envase("fanta", 350), Retornable("sprite", 1500)]

print(filtrar(lista, "Retornable"))
print(filtrar(lista, "Envase"))
```

produce:

```
[Envase retornable sprite, 1500 cc]
[Envase no retornable coca, 350 cc, Envase no retornable fanta, 350 cc]

Process finished with exit code 0
```